# Strange behavior of reference with arrays

Tags: php

```
<?php
 $arr = array(1);
 $a =& $arr[0];
 $arr2 = $arr;
 $arr2[0]++;

 var_dump($arr);
 var_dump($a);
 var_dump($arr2);
?>
```

**Output:**
2
2
2

The element of $arr was changed after increment element of $arr2 though assign was pass-by-value not  pass-by-reference. This happens after definition  the reference $a to $arr[0]. So why this definition modified source array and insert reference to value instead initial value? It looks illogical for me after C++. Is it Bug or the documented feature? I found this [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=20993) and don't found explanations in php 5.5 manual, in manual there is just fact that this can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**PHP: What References Do**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

> Note, however, that *references inside arrays are potentially dangerous*. Doing a normal (not by reference) assignment with a reference on the right side does not turn the left side into a reference, but *references inside arrays are preserved in these normal assignments*. This also applies to function calls where the array is passed by value. Example:

```
<?php
/* Assignment of scalar variables */
$a = 1;
$b =& $a;
$c = $b;
$c = 7; //$c is not a reference; no change to $a or $b

/* Assignment of array variables */
$arr = array(1);
$a =& $arr[0]; //$a and $arr[0] are in the same reference set
$arr2 = $arr; //not an assignment-by-reference!
$arr2[0]++;
/* $a == 2, $arr == array(2) */
/* The contents of $arr are changed even though it's not a reference! */
?>
```

> In other words, the reference behavior of arrays is defined in an element-by-element basis; the *reference behavior of individual elements is dissociated from the reference status of the array container*.

Comment: Sounds like excuse of php developers and then invent usage for this. But not all will expect this behavior. And this is another way to shoot yourself in the foot. I think the real roots of this problem is :
  
***We have discussed this issue and it will put a considerable slowdown on php's performance, to fix this properly. Therefore this behavior will be documented.***

[Link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=20993)

Comment: I completely agree with you, @ratojakuf. It is definitely unexpected, but you had asked if it was a bug or documented. Looking at your link it started as a bug (and still "is"), but my quotes are from the documentation. Are you wondering if they have fixed this in 5.5?

Comment: I think they have larger problems than this).